# How is the NIC driver reported by lshw related to the modules reported by lsmod?

Tags: driver, nic

I am upgrading my internet plan to 300 Mbps and wondering if my configuration can make use of it. Perhaps I need to upgrade my NIC. So loking into the NIC spec I noticed that there is a fairly recent driver release and want to know if I'm using it. So:

```
   lshw -class network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   <....>
   configuration: .... driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k
```

That's the up-to-date driver, but then I run lsmod and to my very limited understanding of lsmod output this driver is not in use. I'm missing something right? Would someone explain please?

```
    lsmod | grep e1000
    e1000e                249856  0
    ptp                    20480  1 e1000e
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero means this module is not used by some other module.
For example, `ptp` is used somehow by `e1000e` (some symbols from this module are needed by `e1000e`).

You may check the driver being used by the NIC if you know the interface name (eg. `eno1`):

```
cat /sys/class/net/eno1/device/uevent
```

The output:

```
DRIVER=e1000e
PCI_CLASS=20000
PCI_ID=8086:1503
PCI_SUBSYS_ID=1043:849C
...
```

Comment: Thank you. So the 'used by' field is not referring to the hardware component but to other modules that use that driver for their implementation. In this case, the NIC driver depends on ptp which depends on pps_core. And pps_core is the module that's right on the metal?  ```lsmod | grep -E 'e1000e|ptp|pps' \n
e1000e                249856  0 \n
ptp                    20480  1 e1000e \n
pps_core               20480  1 ptp\n
```

Comment: So the 'used by' could be because of some dependency in the code, not necessarily a functional dependency. So the e1000e code could be still what uses the hardware api yet the... Oh I see there is quite a lot here to understand here before I can get a clear picture. Thanks though for your explanation. I will put further exploration into my list of things to do.